# Stripping parts of a directory path using php

Tags: php, regex, path

I am looking to strip away a part of the following url yet have no experience with regex or if that's even what I would use.

I have this url:

```
/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Form/Update.php
```

I would like to strip away everything to form:

```
CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Form/Update.php
```

Is there an easy way to do this, and one that is done such that the amount of content before "CoreTheme" could be x characters long, where x is any number.

It should also not match on the word CoreTheme as it might be any name, it should also not match on Aisis-Framework as that could also be any name...

how ever it is safe to assume that anything after CoreTheme is static. The above string will be turned into, using string replace:

```
CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Form_Update.php
```

As I have done in this piece of code:

```
$class_name = str_replace('/', '_', $path . $name);
```

where path is, in my solution, `CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Form/Update.php` and $name is `Update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/" is constant I would just do:

```
str_replace("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/","",$path);
```

Otherwise you would need something constant to get a pattern of, like the number of directories deep or a specific pattern to match.

Comment: I just remembered that through wordpress I can do `wp-get_name()->name` to get `Aisis-Framework` - making that static, is there away to say, remove `wp_get_theme()->name . '/'` leaving me what I want?

Comment: I don't know wordpress specifically, but if wp_get_theme() is a function that simply returns your theme name, something like: $theme = wp_get_theme()-name; $pathyouwant = str_replace($theme."/","",$path) will remove whatever it returned.